# nodeJs + angularJs = not working .directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

help please.
I have simple project https://github.com/A1x1On/nodeJs-AngularJs
I don't understand why angularJs directive doesn't work while angularJs controller works.
These constructions include same and them paths are same, but .directive is broken
Help please.

it's just file with directive, but you better take look at project on git:

```js
(function (angular) {

    'use strict';

    function contaction() {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: '/js/app/contact/templates/contact.template.html',
            scope: true,
            replace: true,
            controller: [
                '$scope',
                function ($scope) {

                    $scope.eww = "ddsf";

                }
            ]
        };
        return directive;
    }

    contaction.$inject = ['contact.factory'];

    angular.module('contact').directive('contdirective', contaction);
})(angular);
```

Comment: what has to do Angular with Node...? :O

Comment: What exactly isn't working?  perhaps you shouldn't be using replace true blindly.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer, just display $scope.eww into the index.html {{eww}} better if contact.template.html will work too)

Comment: @DavidL, $scope.eww into the index.html and contact.template.html for directive